# Airflow 2.0 - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ab_view_menu_name_key" .. Key (name)=(DAG:xxx) already exists

Tags: airflow

I'm upgrading to airflow 2.0, and I'm  this error, I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this. (also this happened when after trying to run '**airflow db upgrade**':

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates 
unique constraint "ab_view_menu_name_key"

/ecs/ds-airflow/dev  DETAIL:  Key (name)=(DAG:vl2_daily) already exists.

ecs/ds-airflow/dev  [SQL: UPDATE ab_view_menu SET name=(%(name_1)s || ab_view_menu.name) 
WHERE ab_view_menu.id IN (%(id_1)s, %(id_2)s, %(id_3)s, %(id_4)s, %(id_5)s, %(id_6)s, 
%(id_7)s, %(id_8)s, %(id_9)s, %(id_10)s, %(id_11)s]

/ecs/ds-airflow/dev  [parameters: {'name_1': 'DAG:', 'id_1': 57, 'id_2': 58, 'id_3': 59, 
'id_4': 60, 'id_5': 61, 'id_6': 62, 'id_7': 63, 'id_8': 64]

ecs/ds-airflow/dev  (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the record from DB manually using the following SQL:

```sql
DELETE FROM ab_view_menu WHERE name = 'DAG:vl2_daily';
```

Comment: thanks for responding! I'm trying to understand this, why does the error happen in the first place?

Comment: Did you by any chance start the Webserver at the same time when you were upgrading DB? If that is the case -- it might have caused it as the Webserver tries to sync permissions too

Comment: I didn't think I did but perhaps. Also, what is ab_view_menu table for?

Comment: It is from Flask-Appbuilder (https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder), the library we(Airflow) use for Airflow Webserver and permissions management. That particular tables defines all the "views" that will have associated "permissions"

Comment: I tried to run   DELETE FROM ab_view_menu WHERE name = 'DAG:vl2_daily';   but I had this error:     ERROR:  update or delete on table "ab_view_menu" violates foreign key constraint "ab_permission_view_view_menu_id_fkey" on table "ab_permission_view"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(191) is still referenced from table "ab_permission_view".    So then I tried this:   delete from ab_permission_view WHERE name = 'DAG:vl2_daily';      but I see this error:     ERROR:  column "name" does not exist WHERE name = 'DAG:vl2_daily';

Comment: @KristiLuna Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @BhanuPrakash yes see kaxil's response

Comment: I am running the same issue, how did you please fix that ? I tried kaxil's response, but it's returning the same error